# error in codeigniter about the query

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I am new in CodeIgniter . Please help me in this query, I am about to get user_typeid. Here is my model query code  which has an error in line 12,

> **Severity: Error**
>
> Message: Call to undefined function get()

What is throwing that error?

```
<?php
class Login_model extends MY_Model {
        function validate($data)
        {
                $condition = "user_email =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "user_password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
                $this->db->select('usertype_id');
                $this->db->from('user');
                $this->db->where($condition);
                $this->db->limit(1);
                $query = $this->db-get();
                if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
                        return $query->row_array();
                }
                else {
                        return NULL;
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have got user_email near $data['username'] should that be user_username?

Comment: its ok sir, in my form i put username but in my database its user_email

Comment: You also can use `$this->db->where('username', $data['username'])` and also `$this->db->where('password', $data['password'])`

Comment: error is clear that you have something wrong with `get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a right arrow `>` before `get()`

```
$query = $this->db-get();
```

This is like you're doing `$this->db` *minus* `get()`, and `get` is not a function.

Should be this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below

And you can also use where like below

```
function validate($data) {
    // It is only going to select usertype_id 
    $this->db->select('usertype_id'); 
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('user_email', $data['username']);
    $this->db->where('user_password', $data['password']);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get(); // missing >

    // if you do not want to use == 1 you can use > 0 

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) { 
       return $query->row_array();
    }  else {
       return FALSE;
    }
}
```